# "no such file to load -- zlib" error when installing a gem

Tags: 11.04, ruby

When I decided to install gem in ubuntu yesterday ( with this command : sudo gem install algorithms ) , bash gave me an error. How can I install gem in ubuntu like that installing on windows ?

************** This is a screenshot from my Terminal ********************

[image]

---

thanks

Comment: Found this on SO but someone ruby-smart should review those answers for an up to date one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-noob-rails-install-fails-on-zlib

Comment: Question abandoned?

Answer (score 5):

*"No such file to load -- zlib"* - gem cannot be installed because it needs library dependency to be installed first. In this case:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Then try to install the *algorithms* gem again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you could put the error message here, it will much easier to get help.

Right now, I have to guess, did you installed RubyGems already?

After that you may also need doing

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Basically you need install zlib first, and using rvm to remove and re-install Ruby. I remembered I did using rvm to install Ruby on Rails last time on Ubuntu 10.04 as well.

In a ideal world, apt should be the one stop shop for every package and will automatically
resolve dependency for you. But it probably will never working that way, unless your package management could compile for you as well when necessary. Gentoo handle Ruby installation slightly better without need rvm to manage Ruby and then Gems manage gems. But using Gentoo to install  Gems is not easier either.

I always thinking Ubuntu or other Linux package manager systems like Portage is much ore better than what Windows have, but in the case of install Ruby Gems Linux doesn't seems any significant simpler or better.

Comment: I modify my post with error message.

Comment: I couldn't vote up yet:( But Both Daniel's or Jorge's link should lead you to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks for the screenshot. Not being snarky, just saving space. I believe your answer is in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769496/ubuntu-noob-rails-install-fails-on-zlib

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31922/problem-installing-ruby-and-gems/31924#31924) *(Link takes you to a Ask Ubuntu answer)* and then trying to install the gem again.

Answer (score -2):

Install rvm on you ubuntu and install  ruby 1.9.2 or any. then you can create a gemset with

```
rvm 1.9.2@blabla --create
```

and run gem install algorithms

Comment: Excuse me , what is the rvm ? how can I install it ?

Comment: sorry i cant rember how i did it cos its been a wile but just did some google search and found this link http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Comment: rvm means ruby version manager

Comment: -1 RVM has nothing to do with this, nor it helps with this problem