# Installing RVM on 11.10

Tags: installation, sudo, ruby, rvm

I have been trying to get RVM properly installed on my system for 10 hours.  The problem is, that when ever I run the command to download the install script I get this:

```
edu@edu-VirtualBox:~$  bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/ruby-rvm': Permission denied
```

If I run the command with sudo, I can get it installed, but then that leads to a whole host of other issues.  Every tutorial I read says that you should not be installing rvm with sudo for a single user install.

Why can I seem to get it installed without running sudo?

Comment: Question - do you absolutely need to install rvm system wide? Because its recommended that you install it per user.

Comment: no sir I don't. I don't know why it keeps trying to install it system wide. How do I enforce that it gets installed in $Home?

Comment: Let me write an answer really quick about how to do this.

Comment: /usr/share/ruby-rvm is a broken path, use this answer to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395

Comment: @mpapis Except that he doesn't need a system wide RVM.

Comment: @jrg that's why the installation command does not include sudo

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue @Guided33?

Answer (score 1):

[As I documented here in another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/31924/6005), this should install RVM on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr remove the /etc/rvmrc file and restart, then install again.

You must have installed the ruby-rvm package at some point which creates a /etc/rvmrc file which sets the rvm_path environment variable to /usr/share/ruby-rvm which requires root privileges. To remove the ruby-rvm package run `sudo apt-get purge ruby-rvm` this is required even if you already ran an apt-get uninstall (since /etc/rvmrc is considered a configuration file)