Jekyll on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to install jekyll. But I am getting this error:
$ gem install jekyll bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Gem::Net::OpenTimeout: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (execution expired) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Gem::Net::OpenTimeout: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (execution expired) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

It should be noted that I have tried multiple times, my internet connection seems ok and the server is also not down. Why is it occurring? How can I fix this issue?
Moreover, I have tested with another gem too, facing the same error:
$ gem install rake
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Gem::Net::OpenTimeout: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (execution expired) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: DotCoverRakeTask, airake, airbrake, airbrake-api, airbrake-extended, airbrake-faraday_sender, airbrake-jets, airbrake-local, airbrake-resque, airbrake-ruby

Here are the installed prerequisites (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/):
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ gem -v
3.5.14

$ gem update --system
ERROR:  Your RubyGems was installed trough APT, and upgrading it through RubyGems
itself is unsupported. If you really need the latest version of RubyGems (tip:
you usually don't), then you need to install RubyGems (and Ruby) manually,
maybe using tools like ruby-install, rvm, etc.

$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.2 (2021-07-07 patchlevel 107) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/rafi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby3.0
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/rafi/.cache/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux-gnu
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/3.0.0
     - /home/rafi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/3.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/rafi/.local/bin
     - /home/rafi/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
     - /snap/bin
     - /home/rafi/.rvm/bin

$ dpkg -l | grep ruby
ii  libruby3.0:amd64                              3.0.2-7ubuntu2.7                                     amd64        Libraries necessary to run Ruby 3.0
ii  rake                                          13.0.6-2                                             all          ruby make-like utility
ii  ruby                                          1:3.0~exp1                                           amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby (default version)
ii  ruby-dev:amd64                                1:3.0~exp1                                           amd64        Header files for compiling extension modules for Ruby (default version)
ii  ruby-full                                     1:3.0~exp1                                           all          Ruby full installation (default version)
ii  ruby-net-telnet                               0.1.1-2                                              all          telnet client library
ii  ruby-rubygems                                 3.3.5-2                                              all          Package management framework for Ruby
ii  ruby-webrick                                  1.7.0-3                                              all          HTTP server toolkit in Ruby
ii  ruby-xmlrpc                                   0.3.2-1ubuntu0.1                                     all          XMLRPC library for Ruby
ii  ruby3.0                                       3.0.2-7ubuntu2.7                                     amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby
ii  ruby3.0-dev:amd64                             3.0.2-7ubuntu2.7                                     amd64        Header files for compiling extension modules for the Ruby 3.0
ii  ruby3.0-doc                                   3.0.2-7ubuntu2.7                                     all          Documentation for Ruby 3.0
ii  rubygems-integration                          1.18                                                 all          integration of Debian Ruby packages with Rubygems

Update
It was set warp-cli connect for the package cloudflare-warp. After switching it to warp-cli disconnect, the errors don't appear for the command:
 sudo gem install jekyll bundler

Why was it happening with warp-cli connect? How can I use gem install keeping warp-cli connect? Do I need set a specific configuration for warp-cli?
And without sudo, it says this:
$ gem install jekyll bundler
Defaulting to user installation because default installation directory (/var/lib/gems/3.0.0) is not writable.
Successfully installed jekyll-4.3.3
Parsing documentation for jekyll-4.3.3
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 0 seconds
Defaulting to user installation because default installation directory (/var/lib/gems/3.0.0) is not writable.
Successfully installed bundler-2.5.14
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.5.14
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
2 gems installed

Another error that is still appearing:
$ sudo gem update --system
ERROR:  Your RubyGems was installed trough APT, and upgrading it through RubyGems
itself is unsupported. If you really need the latest version of RubyGems (tip:
you usually don't), then you need to install RubyGems (and Ruby) manually,
maybe using tools like ruby-install, rvm, etc.

How can I fix it?

Can you install any other gems? Is this a general problem with gems or just this one?

@terdon, check the updated question. I just tested with gem install rake, and got the same error.

dpkg -l | grep ruby please. I did a test right now and have no problems.

@nobody check my updated question.

Please remove package ruby-bundler and try again.

Done, but nothing changes.

okay than we try a non https source. sudo gem install jekyll -s http://rubygems.org And please check if you have a proxy set on your system.

@nobody, I tried it by changing https to http. But it seemed not to affect the error. Maybe the issue is related to network settings. Kindly check my updated question.

it seems it is not possible this way. https://askubuntu.com/questions/31922/problem-installing-ruby-and-gems
